# XERO API - Budget Variance Summary

Tags: xero-api

Has anyone successfully got a budget veriance working from XERO API? It doesn't provide it as an end point and I've been tryingt to come up with soltions to self generate it. But I'm finding bottle necks everywhere I turn.
I was thinking we could fetch all the transactions and build it again locally, but they are lacking massively as each one in the 'BankTransactions' report contains very little details, so I would then need to fetch all the details per transaction, if theres say 1,000 transactions in the last year then we use our 1/5 of our allowance and it's 60 API calls a minute so that will take forever.

Has anyone come up with a solution?

Comment: With [paging](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/banktransactions) you generally pull in 100 transactions at a time

Comment: Yes, but the transactions API does not contain enough information so each transation then needs querying for more information about it. For example, it only includes type i.e. expense not the assign category i.e. Bills.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but by using paging you'd get line item details for each transaction, which includes the account code.  You could get the accounts table and join the transactions and accounts by account code.